# Freemium Model In-App Purchases Sales Tax

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, software

Sales tax for paid apps is somewhat well defined depending on state tax code, things like downloadable or boxed software seem to be covered, and most states will require a sales tax for sold / downloadable apps.

However a grey area is Freemium model apps that rely on in app purchases.

Lets take the simplest scenario as an example, where the app shows Ads and the user can pay $0.99 to remove ads via in app purchase. Now there wasn't any software exchanged at that point, as in no additional screens or in-app / in-game items were added or unlocked.

In this scenario where just ads are removed, is there a need to charge sales tax? Is that considered a software sale ?

This is for US, NY.

Comment: What country are you asking about? Laws vary.

Comment: This is for US, just clarified in the question. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: In the US, there's no sales tax on the Federal level, each State has its own, and the rates may differ between municipalities.

Comment: Added state info the question

Comment: "Somewhat well defined depending on state code" is this referencing the NY state code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that an in app upgrade to ad free is a prewritten change to the software license and would effectively constitute an upgrade of prewritten software.  Below is what seem to be the relevant link and excerpts.

https://www.tax.ny.gov/pubs_and_bulls/tg_bulletins/st/computer_software.htm

> **Sales of software upgrades**
>
> Generally, the sale of a revision or ***upgrade of prewritten software* is
>   subject to tax as the sale of prewritten software**. If, however, the
>   software upgrade is designed and developed to the specifications of a
>   particular purchaser, its sale to that specific purchaser is exempt as
>   a sale of custom software.
>
> **Remotely accessed software**
>
> A sale of computer software includes any transfer of title or
>   possession or both, ***including a license to use.***
>
> When a purchaser remotely accesses software over the Internet, the
>   seller has transferred possession of the software because the
>   purchaser gains constructive possession of the software and the right
>   to use or control the software.
>
> Accordingly, the sale to a purchaser in New York of a license to
>   remotely access software is subject to state and local sales tax.